# Android sensor data isn't smooth

Tags: android, signal-processing, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I have an app that stores sensor data into a database every 10ms, but the signal itself has some very sharp peaks:

[image]

So it doesn't look like the signal is necessarily noisy, its just around the peaks there aren't enough data points surrounding the peak itself to smooth the peak out

**I know I can apply a filter to smooth the signal out**, but I'm wondering whether there is anything that I'm doing wrong when polling the sensors/storing into the database that is causing this behaviour

I would have thought that by using a short polling rate like 10ms would give me more data around the peaks to help smooth the peaks out, but reducing that value `POLL_FREQUENCY` doesn't seem to give me smooth data and I'm not sure why?

I'm collecting the data in a service:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        sensor = event.sensor;

        int i = sensor.getType();
        if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            accelerometerMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            gyroscopeMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
            gravityMatrix = event.values;
        } else if (i == MainActivity.TYPE_MAGNETIC) {
            magneticMatrix = event.values;
        }

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);

        // only allow one update every POLL_FREQUENCY (10ms)
        if(diffTime > POLL_FREQUENCY) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            //insert into database in background thread
            try{
                //this simply takes the value from accelerometerMatrix
                // and the runnable just inserts into the database as a new row
                executor.execute(insertHandler);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "insertData: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

So all this code does is wait for a sensor change event, detect the type of event it is (accelerometer, gyro etc), store the value into the appropriate matrix, and if more than 10ms has elapsed, store the matrix values into the database

Can anyone suggest why the peaks are sharp despite using a short poll frequency (10ms)?

Comment: That's utterly normal for real world sensors-  you don't get nice smooth graphs without a lot of post processing.  However I don't understand why you even have the poll frequency code-  when you request updates you specify a frequency, why do it again?

Comment: Are you referring to the `samplingPeriod` when `registerListener` is called? The problem with that is 1) I need to ensure that I store all of the different sensor values (acc, gyro, etc) at the same time and 2) from what I've read the `samplingPeriod` is pretty variable in when it receives sensor data. So I'm checking to make sure that as long as 10ms (POLL_FREQUENCY) has passed, then get all of my different sensors and store them at the same time

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to.  Your code there isn't actually doing anything-  if the sampling period< POLL_FREQUENCY, you're throwing away data.  If sampling period>POLL_FREQUENCY, that code won't actually do anything, and you aren't getting an actual 10ms frequency, you're getting the higher sampling period.

Comment: Oh also last time I worked with accelerometers, I wasn't able to get more than 100ms polling frequency out of the actual hardware.  That was 2 years ago, but there were parts of the Android framework throttling data so it wouldn't go faster than that.  To get around that I needed a rooted device directly accessing the accelerometer via the dev filesystem.  ANd I needed to override the default hardware settings to turn on a 100 Hz polling frequency (the max the hardware was capable of).  Which broke other parts of Android, like rotation.

Comment: So I'm storing current time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and when I look at the data stored in the DB and check the timestamps, I can see that the time between rows is on the order of 10-12ms. This is without a rooted device, so would it be fair to conclude here that I'm getting polling frequency less than the 100ms you stated? Or is it actually still 100ms of actual hardware polling, but the time I'm seeing is some artifact of the way java/android gets current time in milliseconds?

Comment: You do have 3 separate sensor types coming into there-  are you seeing the faster rate for the accelerometer sensor only, or for any of the 3 returning?  Its also possible that Google has allowed improved accelerometer access in the last 2 years.  Accelerometers generally allow a variety of frequencies, the models used in the Samsung Galaxies in 2012 allowed up to 100 Hz, but Android ran them at 10Hz.  We got 100 Hz out of rooting.

Comment: Also, I see a problem with your db writing code-  you aren't copying the data into the task.  So if at time t=0 an event comes in, at time t=15 a second event comes in, and time t=20 the async task is executed the async task will write the data from t=15, and the data from t=0 will be ignored.  You need to make a deep copy for the data for the thread (not just a reference assignment).

Comment: One other point-  don't use System.currentTimeMillis when dealing with sensor data.  That's the time you're processing the data.  Instead use the time in the sensor event-  that's when the data was generated, which may have been a significant fraction of a second ago if the system was held up.